# An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition invalid URI

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild

Ive created a build definition in VS so that I can queue a build that can be used within Microsoft Test Manager.

However when I queue the build I get an error back:

An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

I dont really know where to start to get to the root cause of this. Can someone point me in the right direction on where I could get more info so that I can narrow this down?

Comment: How and where are you queuing the build from?

Comment: im queuing it from VS 2013 and right clicking on the build def and clicking queue build.

Comment: What version are your Agents and Controller? And what version of TFS?

Comment: Can you verify what port you are connecting on? You need 9091 open between agents and controllers.thats 9191...

Comment: Hrm thats interesting, how can I check the port? I think its 8080

Comment: The port for Controller to Agent coms ins 9191.

Comment: Ok thanks, where can I edit this port?

Comment: You cant, you need to open it in any firewall..

Comment: I think its already open as server im using also hosts a controller for Microsoft Test Manager and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the correct ports are available for TFS to communicate through?

[image: TFS Communication Ports]

You need to have 9191 open for Controllers to Agents for builds.

Comment: Yep I added them into the firewall on both the controller and the agents. Still nothing.

Comment: PS my Agents are on the same machine as the controller

Comment: You need port 8080 open between the TFS server and the Controller!

Comment: I have that open too. Oh well ive tried as much as I can here I think, so i've sent a ticket to our TFS support team. Ill keep this question open so that when they fix it I can post the solution on here so that other people in a similar situation may be able to resolve their problem.